# Python populating all the elements of a 2D list (or array) when I change only one

Tags: python, arrays, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python : how to append new elements in a list of list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219949/python-how-to-append-new-elements-in-a-list-of-list)

I came up with this very strange (for me) behaviour in Python.

I have an empty 2D list (or array if you prefer), and when I add an element to one of it's columns, all the other columns get the same value added.

Here is the code:

```
row = [1, 2, 3, 4]
yChannel = 4*[[]]

sectorPlace = 0
for sector in yChannel:
    sector.append(row[sectorPlace])
    sectorPlace += 1

print yChannel
```

And the output:

> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]

Comment: this is one of the most common doubt in python: see this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219949/python-how-to-append-new-elements-in-a-list-of-list/11220296#11220296>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
yChannel = 4*[[]]
```

creates a list with four times the same list object.  Modifying this single list object will seemingly modify all for sublists, since they are actually all the same list object. You should use

```
yChannel = [[] for dummy in range(4)]
```

to create a list of four *independent* sublists.

Comment: Thanks, that was easy. Problem solved. I will accept you answer as soon as stackoverflow's system allows it.

Answer (score 4):

`yChannel` contains 4 copies of the same list. Compare what you have with:

```
yChannel = [[], [], [], []]
```

Comment: I see, how do I initialize it so the lists are not the same?

Comment: @jbssm: this way, the four lists are initialized as four independent lists. This is the same as [ [] for dummy in range(4) ].

Comment: @Ali: Thanks. I actually need a variable number of lists, but I understand your point.